# Aggregating error bars on a bar chart

Tags: data-visualization, error

I'm creating a clustered bar chart to show the effect of a software change on the performance of an application. There are two independent variables: the benchmark being run (colors) and the input set (clusters). Each bar represents the normalized mean speedup over 10 trials. I added error bars to indicate the standard error of each mean.
[image: cluster plot]

The rightmost cluster represents the means of each color group. I'd like to add error bars to each of these as well, but I don't know what statistic makes sense to use for this.

A. Combine the standard errors from each mean, as described [here](http://www.met.rdg.ac.uk/~swrhgnrj/combining_errors.pdf).

B. Use the standard error of the mean of the means.

Which option is more appropriate? Or is there a statistic that combines A and B somehow?

Comment: What kind of data are "normalized speedups"? Do you have repeated measures or other non-independence in your data?

Comment: I realize now that the term is redundant. Here's how I get one of the bars: Run the benchmark 10 times before the software change, calculate the mean + std error of those values. Repeat for the modified software. Divide "after" mean by the "before" mean, and combine the errors to get the std error of the ratio.